# Pictures in the slider and in the preview of the post - Svelte Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, preview

I have a site with these theme: http://demo.themecobra.com/svelte/ . Everything works fine but I have no idea how i can put a picture so it appears in the slider and the preview of the posts in the main page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your have set featured images for your posts, ideally 940px wide and 500px high.